# Why does "pre-" change the meaning of "dominantly" to mean "for the most part; mainly"?

Tags: meaning, prefixes

Consider the following two sentences:

> People in North America are **predominantly** English speakers.
>
> People in North America are **dominantly** English speakers.

Merriam-Webster defines *predominantly* as "for the most part; mainly"; and while it doesn't directly define *dominantly*, the definition for *dominant* is "commanding, controlling, or prevailing over all others". Therefore, I would take *dominantly* to mean "in a commanding or controlling manner".

What I don't understand is how adding the prefix *pre-* changes the meaning of *dominantly* to the aforementioned definition.

Comment: Nice explanation at http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dominant for the synonyms dominant, predominant, preponderant, paramount, preeminent.

Comment: This simply tells me that appending the prefix "pre-" changes the meaning of dominantly. It doesn't explain why.

Comment: One meaning of the prefix **pre-** is "surpassingly, to the highest degree" (also in pre-eminent, for example). I think this is general reference. It's just by extension from **pre-** = *before in time, rank, order, position, etc.*

Comment: Agreed; it looks like pre- is basically an intensifier here. If anything, the word predominantly seems to, well, predominate, when you talking about numbers.

Comment: Does that mean that dominantly can be used interchangeably with predominantly?

Comment: No, because they are two words with similar but not identical meanings. What I was saying is that I can't assign the difference in their meaning to the prefix itself.

Comment: OP's assumption that "dominantly" means "in a commanding or controlling manner" may be suspect. The standard adverb for this is "domineeringly". Scanning NGram instances for "dominantly" I get the impression it usually relates to the specialised contexts of *dominant genes/musical harmonics/etc.* - paryicularly in older citations. The few later ones using it as a synonym for "predominantly" are probably just misuse arising from erroneous "back-formation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than being a function of its etymology, *predominantly* sounds to this linguist like an analogical neologism based on the following relationships:
*dominate : dominant : dominantly :* -- where all three refer to POWER --
: *predominate : predominant : predominantly* -- where all three refer to NUMBER.
Of course, there is power in numbers, but not always. For example, Old English was the **predominant** language of England after the Norman Conquest, but because French became the **dominant** language, Old English was largely relexified to become Middle English, which can thus be seen as at least in part a French creole.

Answer (score 5):

*Predominant* came into English fully formed, so you'd have to look to its French and Latin forebears for an explanation.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question in any way.

Comment: It makes your question moot -- if "pre" is not a prefix in this case, then asking how "pre" changes "dominantly" is an unanswerable question.  Kind of like how you can't figure out what the "pre" is doing in "preemption" because "emption" isn't a word in English -- "preemtion" came as a whole word from Latin and trying to break it into parts just doesn't work.

Comment: "... trying to break it into *English* parts just doesn't work."